# $.get gives no error but doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create an employee management system, and right now I managed to create a table populated with some database content.

Now what I want is to delete the selected row on click of a button situated at the end of every row.
To do that I'm trying to use the Jquery $.get method, which calls a file named delete.php, that will do the job, and then animate and remove the row from the html.

The problem is: the animation starts, but the php file doesn't remove the record from the database! I even tried to console.log for errors, but as you can see in the below screenshot, it just gives me the html code of the page instead of an error code...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OItRt.jpg)

here's the code I used to generate the table:

```
<?php 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM dipendente";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


            echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>".
                        "<thead>".
                            "<tr>".
                                "<td>id</td>".
                                "<td>nome</td>".
                                "<td>cognome</td>".
                                "<td>impiego</td>".
                                "<td>permessi</td>".
                                "<td>contratto</td>".
                                "<td>inizio</td>".
                                "<td>fine</td>".
                                "<td>edit</td>".
                            "</tr>".
                        "</thead>";

                echo "<tbody>";

                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $id = $row["id"];

                    echo "<tr id=".$row["id"].">".
                            "<td>" . "#". $row["id"]. "</td>" . 
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["nome"]. "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["cognome"] . "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["impiego"] . "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["permessi"] . "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["contratto"] . "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["inizio"] . "</td>".
                            "<td contenteditable='false'>" . $row["fine"] . "</td>".
                            "<td>" . 
                                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span>" . 
                                "&nbsp;" . 
                                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span>" .
                                "<a href='#' id='$id' class='delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>".
                                "&nbsp;".
                                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span>".
                            "</td>".
                        "</tr>";
                }

                echo "</tbody>";

                echo "</table>";


            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
```

here is my jquery code:

```
  $(".delete").click(function(){

    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    console.log(del_id);
    console.log(tr);


    $.get("php/delete.php", { id: del_id } , function(error){
        //console.log(error);
        tr.fadeOut("1s",function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });

});
```

and there's my delete.php code:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['del_id'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'gestione_personale') or die('Connection error!');

$query = "DELETE FROM dipendente WHERE id = '$id'";

mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Database error!');

header('location:../index.php');
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try echoing your `$id` to if that get transferred to you PHP or not.

Comment: I guess this is due to last line `header('location:../index.php');`. And make sure to check console for errors.

Comment: You have to collect the id as `$id = $_GET['id'];` instead of `$id = $_GET['del_id'];`

Comment: Nice eye @siva I missed that.

Comment: @Sand Thanks, I got it from your comment only

Comment: @siva thank you very much! I completely missed that...

Comment: @AlbaOngaro Please upvote if I resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I see I'm going to give this answer. But you really need to get off using `mysqli_*` with the way you're using it. The answer I'm giving you is in prepare statement which is much more secure than the way you're using it.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'gestione_personale') or die('Connection error!');

$query = $dbc->prepare("DELETE FROM dipendente WHERE id = ?");
$query->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);

if($query->execute()){
    header('location:../index.php');
}else{
    die('Database error!')
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I don't know y you guys want to use `header('location:../index.php');` if it is ajax call

Comment: I was just giving him an example of his own code. Right thing is to use `success` in AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try access in URL `delete.php` passing del_id as arg, like this: `delete.php?del_id=1`

Then you'll see if the record is deleted or if you get some error, also check if php `display_errors` is enabled.